# What's the meaning of "COS"?

Tags: dialogue, charlies-angels

In *Charlie's Angels* (2019), Sabina & Jane are acting as a lookout for a meeting between 
Edgar & Elena:

> Jane: **COS** perimeter check.
>
> Sabina: "**COS**"? I have less than no idea what that means, but you are
>   good up here.

What's the meaning of "COS"?

Comment: I'm with Sabrina, have less than no idea what that means

Comment: In the military, COS is an abbreviation for Chief of Staff.  CoS is an abbreviation for Combat Outpost.  Might be the former, as Edgar is a Bosley.

Comment: In US intelligence circles, COS is Chief of Station—the ranking CIA officer at an embassy or other station.

Comment: This is not an answer, but when we were on a Geography field study with an older British dude in India, he would say to do a COS, which to him meant using triangles back in the 1700s to make a map of an area.  Sort of like triangulation, I suppose to get an idea where something is.  The COS referred to cosine in a sort of geographer's slang.  Maybe hollywood spies use COS as slang for the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've now watched this movie 5 times, and this time it just clicked. Jane was probably using two sentences: "COS" and "Perimeter check?" I'm personally thinking it stands for "Client on Site", so Sabina knew Elena has arrived for the meeting and then asking for a perimeter check.